# Ragged tensors in dataset, tensorflow, how do I train the model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have

```
def call (self, inputs):
    context, x = inputs
```

in my model, for fitting,
and my dataset contains ragged tensors, basically context and x are ragged tensor, of variable length, everything I try gives me some sort of error, for example
 first I tried `[ [ context, x], ...]` where all the arrays were `np.ndarray`, but it said something along the lines that `np.ndarray` is an unrecognised datatype and cannot be converted to a `tf.Tensor`.
Then when I tried putting this in a tf.data.Dataset, it says `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).`
I am totally lost on how to train my model

I tried several different data types from list, to tf.data.Dataset, but none of them were working, and now I am totally in the dark. Consulting the documentation has not helped me figure out how does the fit function actually treat data

Comment: Can you show more code here ?